# How to disable Center Key (CK) and let only Left Soft Key (LSK) be used in j2me

Tags: user-interface, command, java-me

I created a custom item in which I need to use the Center Key for the purpose of selecting and I am successfully able to use it with the keyPressed event using the keyCode as -5. The problem is, as soon as I press the CK, it also clicks on the command above the LSK and that causes the menu to pop up. Is there any way that I can disable the CK for a particular command or something like that (because I dont need CK, since I can click on the command through LSK as well, I want to use the CK specifically for the custom item) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CK key is by the phone platform definition does something then as far as I know there is nothing you can do, this is platform default. which device do you try this on?
Adam.

Comment: Hi Adam,

thanks for your reply. I could solve the issue by using a trick.I disabled the commmandlistener for the class while detecting the LSK and RSK press events from the custom item's keypressed method.. I can do that since the custom item is the only focusable item in the form. 

Thanks,
Ashish.